# schema mongoose con propiedad calculada

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Buen día para todos.

me estoy adentrando en el mundo de nodejs y mongodb y me encuentro con la siguiente situación, estoy realizando el schema en mongoose y tengo un campo que requiero que sea calculado. esto es posible sin tener el registro guardado en la base de datos? el campo es iva, leí en la documentación que con default y realizando una función se podría, pero node me devuelve un error.

aquí esta mi Schema, muchas gracias por la colaboración.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const FacturaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    factura:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    producto:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    cantidad:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    precio:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    iva:{
        type: Number,
        default: function(){
            let iva = ((cantidad * precio) * 0.19);
            return iva
        }
    }
```

Comment: el tema es que no tienes valores en los campos que estás utilizando para el cálculo, además de que quizás deberías probar poner this.cantidad y this.precio, ya que es un método, o sea función dentro de un objeto. En Mongoose tenés un hook llamado pre, que te permite hacer algo en el ciclo que desees, o sea, antes de guardar, despues de guardar, etc. También existe un post, pero te diría que lo hagas con prev, es decir, haces el cálculo y luego guardas el valor calculado. Hay ejemplos en la documentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Ya te han indicado una forma de hacerlo usando un middleware de tipo `pre`, sin embargo tal como lo estabas intentando (usando un atributo `dafault`) es posible hacerlo.

El problema radica en que no estás usando la palabra `this` para referirte al documento que estás creando al ejecutar `save()`. El valor por defecto (`default`) sólo será calculado al crear una instancia nueva (`new`) del documento para ser salvado en base de datos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Teniendo como referencia tu esquema de datos, el campo `default` debería escribirse de la siguiente forma:

```js
default: function() {
  return (this.precio * this.cantidad) * tasa;
}
```

donde `this.precio` y `this.cantidad` se refieren a sus respectivos campos, y `tasa` será el valor de IVA aplicado, que como puedes observar lo he colocado como una variable, ya que de esta forma te será más fácil manejar los cambios en el mismo.

Tu esquema de datos se puede ver de la siguiente forma:

```js
const tasa = 0.19;

const FacturaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  factura:{
      type: Number,
      require: true
  },
  producto:{
      type: String,
      require: true
  },
  cantidad:{
      type: Number,
      require: true
  },
  precio:{
      type: Number,
      require: true
  },
  iva:{
      type: Number,
      default: function() {
        return (this.precio * this.cantidad) * tasa;
      },
  }
},
{collection: "facturas", timestamps: true});
```

El campo por defecto será creado sólo al salvar un nuevo documento usando `save()` sobre la instancia del mismo:

```js
const factura = new Factura({
  factura: 1,
  producto: "Producto 1",
  cantidad: 3,
  precio: 10
});

factura.save((err, saved) => {
  if(err) {
    console.error("Error saving document!");
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(saved);
});

// produce lo siguiente:
{
  factura: 1,
  producto: 'Producto 1',
  cantidad: 3,
  precio: 10,
  _id: new ObjectId("61bee7ddc45e45180488bfa5"),
  iva: 5.7,
  createdAt: 2021-12-19T08:05:49.747Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-12-19T08:05:49.747Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Toma en cuenta que esto no funcionará si estás actualizando un documento existente, tampoco funcionará el middleware `pre` de la otra respuesta.

Si deseas establecer el valor durante una actualización debes hacerlo de forma explícita, calculando el porcentaje de IVA a mano antes de actualizar el documento. Claro, que las facturas se entienden como documentos inmutables, por lo cual, hacerlo de esta forma no estaría mal si ese fuese el caso.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 2):

Como te mencionaba en el comentario, existen hooks en Mongoose, como pre y post, podrías intentar algo así.

```
const FacturaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    factura:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    producto:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    cantidad:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    precio:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    iva:{
        type: Number,
        require: true
    }
})

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    this.iva = (this.cantidad * this.precio) * 0.19;
    next();
  });
```

Aquí le decimos que antes de guardar, a iva le de como resultado la operación de (cantidad*precio) * 0.19, luego continúe, en este caso guarde.